# list of differentiations ( Maclaurin expansion)

Tags: haskell, iteration, differentiation

Here,I have a diff function which can be used to differentiate.

for example diff (sin x) ("x")= cos x

(here,(sin x) is the function, ("x") is the variable i want to differentiate)

How to use iterate to generate a list of differentiations of function [f(x),f'(x),f'(x),f''(x)....]

Comment: use "iterate"command

Comment: For future questions, please quote proper declarations of the functions you're talking about (type signatures!) and use Markdown to make your post nicely readable.

Comment: An OT suggestion: when programming, especially in a functional programming language, please try to unlearn the bad habit of saying "`sin x` is a function" when actually meaning "`\x -> sin x` is a function". In your case, I guess, `sin x` is actually some value representing an _expression_, i.e. a piece of syntax, using a suitable data type. If that's the case, it is likely not written as `sin x` at all, in Haskell. So, as @leftaroundabout said, try to be clear about the involved types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flip` in conjunction with `iterate`:

```
(flip diff) "x" f = diff f "x"
```

so

```
iterate ((flip diff) "x") f = [ f, f', f'', ...]
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to flip the definition of `diff` itself, so you can write `diff "x"` as the differential operator ∂/∂x. (Also, it would probably be better to change the type of the differentiation-variable: "magic strings" aren't very nice...)